# What is the correct way to organize (and referer to) a set of CodeQL queries?

Tags: github, github-actions, codeql

I am learning CodeQL and I now have several custom CodeQL queries for a Java library that we use. The queries run in VSCode, if I run them one by one. I would like to be able to use them duing the Github Workflow.

My understanding is that I need to create a query pack for this, or perhaps a query suite. I am not sure what the difference between the two is.

Based on the CodeQL CLI documentation, I can't tell how one can run such query packs from the command-line. From what I have seen in the [github/codeql-action](https://github.com/github/codeql-action), you need to list these queries one by one. Surely there must be a better way.

I want to try it out locally before pushing it to a Github repository.

I have the following directory structure:

```
my-codeql-queries/
+ query1.ql
+ query2.ql
+ query3.ql
+ queries.xml
+ qlpack.yml
```

These are the contents of the:

- `queries.xml`:

```
<queries language="java"/>
```

- `qlpack.ql`:

```
name: my-codeql-queries
version: 1.0.0
dependencies:
  codeql/java-all: "*"
suites: my-codeql-queries
```

So, my questions are how can I create a CodeQL query pack and:

- Use the CodeQL CLI to run this from the command-line
- Use the [github/codeql-action](https://github.com/github/codeql-action) to run it in a Github Workflow
- What should be the directory structure of the Git repository, in order for them to be able to be re-usable and imported from other repositories and Github Workflows?
- Do these queries need to be compiled? (And, if so, how?).

Comment: Have you looked at the custom configuration file? See https://github.com/github/codeql-action#configuration-file and https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/customizing-code-scanning#using-a-custom-configuration-file.